# Dot product two array

Tags: c, arrays, vector

Im trying to write a program that take two arrays on different printf input, and then compute the dot product, so far this is where i get, i need help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 8
float droprod(float x[], float y[], int size[]);

int main()
{
    int i ;
    int Vx[SIZE], Vy[SIZE] ;

    printf("Enter 1st vector (q to quit) ");
    for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    { 
                scanf("%d", &Vx[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter 2nd vector (q to quit) ");
    for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
                    scanf("%d", &Vy[i]);
    }

printf("vectors [%d] [[%d] ", Vx[SIZE], Vy[SIZE]); // to double check my input, and it is not giving me the right input.

return 0;
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? What output are you receiving and what output are you expecting? Does your problem occur for all inputs or just some? It's very difficult to help with such a vague question.

Comment: `Vx[SIZE]` out of range

Answer (score 2):

`printf` cannot directly print arrays. You must print each element manually using, say, a `for` loop:

```
printf("vectors [");
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    if(i != 0) {
        printf(", ");
    }
    printf("%d", Vx[i]);
}
printf("] [");
/* same for the other array */
printf("]");
```

You could even wrap that logic in a function:

```
void print_vector(int vec[SIZE]) {
    printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if(i != 0) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        printf("%d", vec[i]);
    }
    printf("]");
}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
printf("vectors ");
print_vector(Vx);
printf(" ");
print_vector(Vy);
```

Comment: Why not make a single function that prints a vector? Instead of /* same for the other array */ ?

Comment: The purpose of the answers is to demonstrate a solution, not to always write the most ideal possible code. We'd all be here all day if we tried to do that. If modularity is desired, the asker may easily add it.

Comment: @icktoofay thank you, how to i go about doing the dot product

Comment: @user2238405: To take a dot product, you sum the products of the first elements of both vectors, the second elements of both vectors, and so on. This suggests a straightforward method: begin with a variable initialized to zero. Use a `for` loop to loop through the valid indices, adding the product of element of the two vectors at that index. The variable now holds the sum of the products, e.g., the dot product.